# How to be able to receive background notifications with FCM on iOS (android already works)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Flutter app the admin users can send notifications to the others users through FCM. In android already works but in iOS the notification arrives only with the app opened. I already tried many things on internet and still don't working.

This is the dart code that manages the pushs:

```dart
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }

  // Or do other work.
}


class PushNotificationsManager {

  PushNotificationsManager._();

  factory PushNotificationsManager() => _instance;

  static final PushNotificationsManager _instance = PushNotificationsManager
      ._();

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final NotificationPlugin _notificationPlugin = NotificationPlugin();

  Future<void> init() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
          IosNotificationSettings());
    }
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      // Called when the app is in the foreground and we receive a push notif.
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
        print(message['notification']['body']);
        _notificationPlugin.showNotification(
            title: 'TEST',
            content: message['notification']['body']
        );
        //sendNotification();
      },
      // Called when the app has been closed completely and its opened
      // from the notification directly

      //onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isAndroid ? myBackgroundMessageHandler:null,
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        if(Platform.isIOS){
          message = _modifyNotificationJson(message);
        }
      },
      // Called when the app is in the background and its opened from the notif
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
        if(Platform.isIOS){
          message = _modifyNotificationJson(message);
        }
      },
    );

  }

  Map _modifyNotificationJson(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    message['data'] = Map.from(message ?? {});
    message['notification'] = message['aps']['alert'];
    return message;
  }


  Future sendNotification(String body, String title) async {
    final String url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    var notification;
    notification =
    '{"notification": {"body": "${body}", "title": "${title}", "content_available": "true", "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"}, "priority": "high", "to": "MYTOPIC"}';
    final response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: <String, String>{
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5",
          "Authorization": "key=MYKEY"
        },
        body: notification
    );

    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I already enabled pushNotifications and background modes in xcode, already check my certificates but the problem stands. Someone could help me?

Comment: You are expecting your app to receive a notification with only 16 lines of code?

Comment: That is what the documentation say https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything from the appdelegate.swift didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and keep only the two below lines.

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

Ask for permission from fcm plugin see if background notifications show up now.

Removing the below code prevents any foreground notification which is the default behaviour, you can use an overlay to show foreground notification.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
```

Then send a test notification from Firebase Console. See if it works.

Comment: I tried this and continues with the same behavior

Comment: With both `false`and 'string NO`

Comment: Try sending a test push notification (Using fcm token) while in foreground from Firebase Console, if you receive notification try it in background and terminated mode as well. See if you're getting notifications. If so then there is a problem with backend.

Comment: The same behavior.. Only show if I open the app. With it opened the push is showed normally

Comment: I'm since day 9 on it... I don't know what to do